# Eclipse : creating a custom view with tabs

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create a tabbed properties panel by following this example,

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html

But the example code in here doesnt actually create the tabs mentioned in the article. I think there is an issue with the example code.

EDIT: Pardon me for the confusion. I want to create a custom view that contains tabs. This example changes the Properties view to show tabs. Can someone suggest some examples and sample code?

Answer (score 0):

That is the best example I've come across for Tabbed Properties. If there is an issue, then you have to file a bug: http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using the properties view stand-alone I'm afraid, but you might want to consider the [multi-page editor](http://wiki.bioclipse.net/index.php?title=How_to_write_a_Multi_Page_Editor) instead. Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html).

Comment: Ah, in that case, that doesn't help :)